# arm-linux-androideabi-g++: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin.so not found

Tags: android, gcc, lto

When I compiled Chrome V8 under ubuntu 12.04, I encountered a problem that is

> arm-linux-androideabi-g++:fatal error, -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin.so not found

The ndk version is r8b. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

When you extra the `android-ndk-*.tar.bz2`, it should create a symlink named `liblto_plugin.so`to the real file `liblto_plugin.so.?.?.?`.

If you have a problem creating symlinks (e.g. a shared directory in a virtual machine), the symlink won't be created and the problem will occur.
Try re-extracting the `.tar.bz2` file to a filesystem that supports symlinks and verify that `liblto_plugin.so` exists.

Comment: that makes no sense.  what does it mean to "parse the...".  why the heck would you parse it?  if you mean inflate/extract, then how does inflating create a link to the real liblto?  how does it know where the real liblto is?

Comment: @thang: Presumably the "parse the" part is an ESL (english as a second language) issue. As for how it knows where the real liblto_plugin.so is, that's presumably because the real liblto_plugin.so comes from the very same tarball (and it's a relative symlink).

Answer (score 1):

I found that there were a number of liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0 files in my android source tree and that copying the one in `<source_folder>/android/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0` to `liblto_plugin.so` in the same location fixed the problem.

I suspect maybe the original was a link to the `.0.0.0` version but didn't survive the zip or rsync process I used to copy the source tree to my machine.