# fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin.so not found

Tags: android, webrtc

I am trying to compile the webrtc source code.Now when I execute the " ninja -C out/Debug peerconnection_server" ,it reminds me : 
  fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin.so not found

I don't know how it cause,anynone have come accross the same problem?

Comment: This loooks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19272524/294313